# What word or phrase describes this musical instrument?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

The last time I saw one in the streets was back in the early 1960s, and it drew the attention of all passers-by as most people had never seen one before. Let me describe it:

- It consists of a box with a drawer and a hand crank.
- Turning the crank in a circular motion produces music.
- The drawer contains a lot of tiny cards telling one's fortune.
- A lovebird, or a monkey, often has a role in the show.

This instrument is his owner's bread and butter. He walks around parks and squares, turning the crank to produce music.  When he spots a couple, he offers the man a fortune-card for his girlfriend or wife. If the guy accepts it, the lovebird picks up a card for the couple, and the instrument owner gets a tip.

Comment: The drawer normally contains the *pinned barrels* used to store the music. We can imagine that fortune cards have been recently added by the organ grinder for commercial purpose.

Comment: When I was a kid this was always referred to (in reading books) as a "box organ".  Generally came with the monkey.  I think I may have even seen one in operation once.  Never read anything about the cards, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That would be called a ***barrel organ***. The person who plays it is called an ***organ grinder***. I've only seen them on TV and in movies, and I've never seen the fortune card part of it. Just the musical instrument.

[image]

(Barrel organ - Britannica.com)

Comment: The one I saw was much smaller, had a crank, no wheels, and the guy carried it with a leather strap around his neck.

Comment: A conceptually similar instrument is the Hurdy-Gurdy.  Also operated by a crank, though the player does have to press keys with their other hand to make notes, rather than _just_ cranking it.  There's also the music box, which can be spring-loaded or operate on a crank (e.g. a Jack-in-the-Box).  These work by tweaking tuned metal tines with pegs on a rotary drum.  The one in this answer is probably closer to what you're thinking though - they come in a wide variety of sizes.  (It does have a crank, it's just hidden from view near the man's right hand.)

Comment: _The one I saw was much smaller, had a crank, no wheels, and the guy carried it with a leather strap around his neck._ Still a barrel organ. You might see the instument referred to as a "hurdy -gurdy", but that is actually a different instrument, with strings rather than pipes, a rotating wheel, and keys to stop the strings. (Just seen Darrel's comment which arrived while I was typing.)

Comment: **There are no wheels** on the organ in the picture, either. Look closely and you will notice that it is just sitting on top of a push cart. The bloke's red umbrella is also sitting on the cart.

Comment: @Drew  I really missed that and you are a good observer.  Then again, what I mean is that the guy carries it close to his chest.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The *only* thing an hurdy-gurdy and a barrel organ have in common is a crank. The hurdy-gurdy is a bowed instrument; its crank only make a wheel turn which, in turn rub the strings, some of which can be “shortened” like on a violin but through a keyboard; it is also used for rhythmic purposes. The barrel organ is a wind instrument, its crack is used to produce air pressure (using bellows) and to rotate a barrel which opens pipes to play the melody. The hurry-gurdy is as related to the barrel organ as it is to the saxophone, which also has keys.

Comment: @Édouard - The OP didn't say anything about what kind of sound it produced.  The only thing we knew is there's a crank on it, so I listed a few other instruments that use cranks.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Then propose it as a possible answer, or say in a comment the OP might be looking for a hurdy-gurdy and not a barrel organ. But don’t say they conceptually similar, they are absolutely not.

Comment: @Édouard - I would have, but I still believe that barrel organ is probably the correct answer, so I didn't want to propose an answer that I believed to be most likely wrong, which is why I made it a comment instead.  As for similarities, they're as similar to each other as either is to a jack-in-the-box, in that they're all crank-operated.  That's all I meant by that.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the OP's question is definitely "Barrel Organ" but there is a degree of confusion about what this term means and also around the terms **Barrel Organ** and **Hurdy-Gurdy**. In particular there is a comment discussion going on between @DarrelHoffman and @Édouard. I was going to add my own comment when I found [this site](http://www.johnsmithbusker.co.uk) belonging to a maker of barrel organs from which I copied the following paragraph:

*To clear up some common misconceptions, these pages are devoted to 'organs' - that is, instruments with pipes that sound when air is blown through them, just like a church organ, but a lot smaller!   'Barrel Organs' were a common sight years ago, and some did contain air-blown pipes, but the majority of these were actually very large versions of a musical box - as revealed by the 'metallic' sounds that they produced.   Another name sometimes wrongly applied to Busker organs is 'Hurdy Gurdy'.   This is actually a mechanical violin, where a rotating wheel takes the place of a bow, and notes can be sounded by operating keys to press the violin strings onto the wheel.*

This said so much that I wanted to say and with so much authority that I thought I should share it with the community. The only thing I would add is that true [hurdy-gurdies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurdy-gurdy)
are instruments which need proper musical skills to play whereas barrel organs of all types are hand-cranked mechanical instruments where the tune is determined by spikes on a rotating drum or holes in cards or paper. For those who are interested I would suggest that they enter "hurdy-gurdy" into a search engine. There is a wealth of information and demonstrations out there.